# How to manage duplicate ajax URLs for search engines

Tags: seo, search-engine-indexing, google-index, canonical-url

If you use ajax URLs like **example.com/#!explore** - and you happen to have another URL that shows the same content, for example **example.com/#!explore/world** - how can you tell a service engine that both URLs show the same content?

Of course, one could redirect one URL to the other, but this would only be possible through JavaScript and therefore be slow - and probably confusing for crawlers...

Can you use canonical tags (with or without the hash tag)?

Comment: Hash bang crawling from `#!` URLs has been deprecated.   Google isn't going to support that anymore.   You should just remove the `!` from your URLs at this point.

Comment: I know that this ajax hash URL suggestion is deprecated, nevertheless does Google still have our old URLs indexed, e.g. https://www.lookr.com/#!explore/russia - so if we switch to URLs without the "!", we need to somehow redirect them, or mark them as duplicate. How do we do that properly?

Comment: That is a good question.   Hopefully, somebody has done this before, but if you end up experimenting, you can answer your own question here afterwards.   I'm not sure which of these would actually work for Google (possibly any of them):   1.  301 redirect the `_escaped_fragment` URL.   2. Change the hash using JavaScript.  3. Insert dynamic canonical tags using JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you. These are actually good suggestions. But since there are many other ajax websites around, I really would like to have an official recommendation from Google how to deal with it - to be on the safe side...